# document.getElementsByClassName if an element can contain other classes as well

Tags: javascript

How can I find elements by a certain class but which can contain other classes as well? In pure javascript. `document.getElementsByClassName` only can find elements by an exact class name.

Comment: MSDN - [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Read up about `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` but if the parent you need you might need to do some traversing.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` finds all elements with specified class name, even when multiple classes are added.

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('c1').length)
```

```html
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c1 c2"></div>
<div class="c1 c2 c3"></div>
<div class="c11"></div>
<div class="c12"></div>
```